# why is it i see System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: every time i click insert Button?

Tags: c#

Every time i click insert this code will insert well but when i open access database this is how it puts on each cell System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 
here is my insert code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    @"Data source= C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\crt_db.accdb";
    conn.Open();

    String my_querry = (@"INSERT INTO System (Name, Address, Conperson, Scope_of_certification, Certification, Date_issued,
                        Dateofsurv, Dateofrecerti, Remark, certi_fee)
                 VALUES ('" + txtName + "','" + txtAddress + "','" + txtConperson + "','" + txtscoperofcerti + "','" + txtcertification + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + txtRemark + "','" + txtcertfee + "')");

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: *Please* stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized queries instead. See http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, stop using concatenated query strings, as this will leave you open to SQL injection attacks and also cause multiple other problems, for example when passing `DateTime` values! Use parameterized queries like this. Also, please note that you need to insert `TextBox.Text`, not `TextBox` into the database for correct values:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    @"Data source= C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\crt_db.accdb";
    conn.Open();

    String my_querry = @"INSERT INTO System (Name, Address, Conperson, Scope_of_certification, Certification, Date_issued,
                        Dateofsurv, Dateofrecerti, Remark, certi_fee)
                 VALUES (@name, @address, @conPerson, @scope, @cert, @dateIssued, ...");

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
    ...
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateIssued", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Also: Please get used to storing dates as `DateTime` or `Date` and not as text. Please also note how I use `DateTime.Now` as parameter value. It does work with all data types. In your case (until you've changed to the `DateTime/Date` column type) you need to use `dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 3):

You are directly accessing `TextBox` control, you need to access its `Text` property to access its content.

Replace This:

```
txtName
```

With This:

```
txtName.Text
```

Same for rest of the controls.

**Suggestion :** Your query is open to SQL injection attacks use Parameterised queries to avoid them.