# Appending a text value from a combo box in WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

So currently I have a combo box with three values in:

- C
- V
- CV

I have created a text box and put this onto my form, which grabs the data selected from the combo box, and displays the selected option. The code for this resides in my combo box:

```
    txtCarVan.Text = cboCarVan.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

However, when I append the data from this text box into my SQL table, it appears like so:

System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: C

How can I make it so that the only thing appended into the field is the option selected?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` is not WPF, but WinForms. Please edit your question tags and title accordingly.

Comment: You need to grab `txtCarVan.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are passing txtCarVan into the SQL instead of txtCarVan.Text.

[why is it i see System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: every time i click insert Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707608/why-is-it-i-see-system-windows-forms-textbox-text-every-time-i-click-insert-bu)